# Binding element 'note' implicitly has an 'any' type

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am getting the error which I'm sure is due to typescript.  This is an example that I am trying to get to work.  I use js server to import a few notes.  The error is a red line under the {note} in the NoteCard.tsx file.  Can someone please help me understand how to using these properties.

here is my notecard.tsx

```
export default function NoteCard({ note }) {  return <div>{note.title}</div>;}
```

here is my notes.tsx

```
export default function Notes() {
const [notes, setNotes] = useState<any[]>([]);

useEffect(() => {
fetch("http://localhost:8000/notes")
  .then((res) => res.json())
  .then((data) => setNotes(data));
}, []);

return (
<Container>
  <Grid container>
    {notes.map((note) => (
      <Grid item key={note.id} xs={4} md={4} lg={4}>
        <NoteCard note={note} />
        {/* <Paper>{note.title}</Paper> */}
      </Grid>
    ))}
  </Grid>
</Container>
);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding a props interface to the NoteCard function

```
interface NoteCardProps {
  note: {
    title: string
  }
}

export default function NoteCard({ note }: NoteCardProps) {  return <div>{note.title}</div>;}
```

Comment: thanks... is this the proper way to itemize the things I have in props?  Is this considered good practice to always do it this way?

Comment: It’s debatable, I always prefer to have the type/interface (one of the benefits of ts is the type check). You can even export the interface or have a separate file with all types. It’s not good practice to use the any type when you know that the object has a set structure

Answer (score 6):

The *implicit* wording is not a coincidence. You can simply type the function, and give it an *explicit* type.

```
export default function NoteCard({ note }: { note: any }) {  return <div>{note.title}</div>;}
```

This should fix the warning.

Comment: thank you for your input

Comment: A slight note is that using using any in TypeScript is not too wanted, as then you're back to dynamic typing. See my other answer for how I would personally write the code.

Answer (score 0):

My other answer explains how to eliminate the linter-warning. However, it does not address the underlying issues with the code. One of the main benefits of using TypeScript, is that it's statically typed with the help of *types*. The type *any* is the highest type, similar to *Object* in Java; all types are a sub-type of *any*. The *any*-type should be avoided when possible, as you're practically using dynamic typing again; this means that you're more or less back to using plain JavaScript.

Just for completness sake, I'll add a snippet showing how I would write such a component.

```
export type Note = {
  title: string
}

export default function NoteCard({note}: {note: Note}) {
  return <>{note.title}</>
}
```

```
export default function Notes() {
  const [notes, setNotes] = useState<Note[]>([])
  // Rest of Notes.tsx  
}
```